# Replacing value of input only one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm able to replace/remove a certain value of an input when a label is clicked, here is my code:

```
$("#labelid").on("click",function() {
    if($("#inputid").val('sometexthere'));
    {
    $("#inputid").val('');
    }
});
```

The code deletes the value `sometexthere` each time the label is clicked. I want to limit this to only once, so if the label is clicked for the first time it deletes the value and if it clicked for the second time, it does nothing (leave value as it is).

How can I do this?
Answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just use the HTML placeholder attribute in the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **[`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/)** method.

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type.

---

```
$("#labelid").one("click",function() {
    if($("#inputid").val() === 'sometexthere')   // remove the ;
    {
        $("#inputid").val('');
    }
});
```

The `val('...')`in `if($("#inputid").val('sometexthere'))` is assigning the value, and not comparing - `$("#inputid").val() === '...'` .

> **Note** : As [j08691 suggests here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473749/replacing-value-of-input-only-one-time/#comment47108671_29473848) if its just related to initial text/placeholder use `<input placeholder="sometexthere"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
var click = false;
$("#labelid").on("click",function() { 
  if(!click){ 
    if($("#inputid").val('sometexthere'));
    {
           $("#inputid").val(''); 
    }
   click = true;
  }
});
```

this will work :)

Comment: No it wont ;). Have you tried it? `if($("#inputid").val('sometexthere'));` **sets** the value.

Comment: Still no. Your code will clear the input **every time** the label is clicked. Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/53eabt9g/

Comment: updated it . . sorry . . the && won't work . .i don't know why: http://jsfiddle.net/anst2vbc/

Comment: I hate to do this but you are missing the point. The script still only LOOKS like its working. The line 'if($("#inputid").val('sometexthere'));' is SETTING not checking the value and so always evaluates as true. See:http://jsfiddle.net/anst2vbc/1/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery.off()](https://api.jquery.com/off/) after the link is clicked the first time.  I think the placeholder is a nice idea, but I don't know if it accomplishes what you want, and if you need backwards compatibility you would need a shim to handle the `placeholder` property.  I agree with the accepted answer *if* the *detachment* of the event handler *is unconditional*.

If detachment of the event handler is conditional, I think this is cleaner:

```
$("#labelid").on("click",function() {
    var $input = $("#inputid");

    if($input.val().length > 0) {
        $input.val('');
        $(this).off("click");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `$("#inputid").val('sometexthere')` is always `true` because what is happening there is setting a value to the field. The `val` method returns `jQuery` object so it is basically truthy.

One of the solutions indeed is the [`.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) method which assigns the event listener only once. However, you may need to do other things on the `click` event. So I'll go with a flag:

```
var flag = true;
$("#labelid").on("click",function() {
    var input = $("#inputid");
    var current = input.val();
    if(current === 'sometexthere' && flag) {
      flag = false;
      input.val('');
    }
});
```

And by the way, consider the usage of the [placeholder](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#placeholder) attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In case you've been persuaded by the argument to use a placeholder instead here's an example implementation that includes a fallback for browsers that [don't natively support HTML5 Placeholders](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) (ahem <=IE9)...

```js
$(function() {
    //test if placeholder is natively supported:
    function hasPlaceholder() {
        var test = document.createElement('input');
        return ('placeholder' in test);
    }
    //if placeholder is not natively supported initialise this method to replicate the behaviour
    if(!hasPlaceholder){
        $('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val() == $this.attr('placeholder')) {
                $this.val('')
                     .removeClass('placeholder');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.val() == '' || $this.val() == $this.attr('placeholder')) {
                $this.addClass('placeholder')
                     .val($this.attr('placeholder'));
            }
        }).blur();
        //on submit, make sure we remove any fo placeholder values
        $('[placeholder]').parents('form').submit(function() {
            $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if ($this.val() == $this.attr('placeholder')) {
                    $this.val('');
                }
            })
        });
    }
});
```

```css
/* You can style placeholders... */
input.placeholder {color:#66aaee;}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #66aaee;}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #66aaee;}
::-moz-placeholder {color: #66aaee;}
:-ms-input-placeholder {color: #66aaee;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Label: <input name="inputname" id="inputid" placeholder="this is the placeholder" /></label>
```